# How to convert this SQL code to Power Apps?

Tags: sql, powerapps

I have a SQL query that shows me the latest record for a group in my database. To get the latest record for each group, I use the `ID` column, which is an auto-increment column. The highest ID number will be the latest record.

However I cannot convert this to a similar code in Power Apps gallery.

```
SELECT        *
-- from my table
FROM            dbo.MyTable
-- where ID is the maximum ID grouped by product_ID
WHERE        (ID IN
                             (SELECT        MAX(ID)
                               FROM            dbo.MyTable
                               GROUP BY product_ID))

and Product_Type = 'Vegetables'
```

My attempt, is it close?

```
ForAll(    
    GroupBy(
        SortByColumns(
            Filter(MyTable, Product_Type ='Vegetables'),
            'product_ID', Ascending, 'ID', Descending),
        'product_ID', '_recs'
    ),
    Patch(First(_recs), {product_ID: product_ID})
)
```

I understand some of these functions are not "delegable" which may be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Distinct(
  MyTable,
  product_id
).Result
```

This should give you an array of all unique product id's.
Now, if you place it on a gallery, you can add a label to each row where you display a text label with the default text value:

```
First(
SortByColumns(
  Filter(
    MyTable,
    product_id=ThisItem.product_id
  ),
  "ID",
  "Descending"
  )
).ID
```

Basically, you take the product ID's and look up the max ID for every row.

There are multiple options, and this might need some tweaking, but this will get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However we ended up using SQL views instead to get the latest records.